# Why might the BIOS report the wrong size for an HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, hardware-failure

I have four HDDs in my system.

1. Seagate 250GB (boot drive with Windows 8 RTM installed)
2. Samsung 500GB
3. Samsung 1.5TB
4. Western Digital 200GB

I recently had my power supply fail and after replacing it one of the drives, the Samsung 1.5TB, that was working fine before is being reported by the BIOS as a 500GB drive. Disk Manager in Windows shows it to contain a 500GB Raw partition. The other three drives appear to be fine.

The drive is a Samsung SpinPoint F4EG HD155UI 1.5TB drive and the BIOS correctly reports it as a **Samsung HD155UI** but shows the size as 500GB. Going into the drive details in the BIOS and requesting an auto detect of the drive has no effect. I see from searching earlier that these drives have a firmware bug that can cause data loss. I have never applied the patch and having had the drive from new it probably doesn't have the patch installed. But this problem isn't what I would think of as data loss so perhaps the firmware bug is unrelated.

Is it likely that the drive was damaged by power issues as the power supply failed? I could understand if the file system or data on it was damaged but I've never seen a problem like this before.

Comment: I've never seen such a problem either. You can try booting up using Seadate's SeaTools ISO, and see what it has to say about the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Still have no idea of the exact cause of the problem but after installing the [Samsung HD204UI_JP.exe Firmware Patch/Update](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223571en?language=en_US) the drive appears as normal again.